# IIS server : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

I have recently migrated my portal into IIS server through iisnode. I see the error

```
POST https://portal.website/api/abc net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)
POST https://portal.website/api/xyznet::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)
```

I tried to see if all the settings inside IIS is good. All the settings seems to be perfect.

Can anyone suggest what is going wrong?

Comment: are you trying to request using http/2?also, try to clear browser history and data and again try to access site.

Comment: Hi Jalpa Panchal, we are not using http/2 . I cleared cookies and history. Tried to access the site. I see same issue

Comment: Could you share which iis version and web browser you are using?

Comment: Hi @JanviPanchal, thanks for help. I fixed this issue as data dumped in database was more. So I filtered data fetched by API.

Comment: I am glad that your issue is resolved. I suggest you post the solution as an answer and mark that, This will help other people who face the same issue.

Comment: Seriously, that would have been nice to tell us how you fixed it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there is post Http Reset for API, please check the data fetched by this API. This might be due to API getting timeout.